# Can a Voice action button be added next to edittext in android

Tags: android

Can we have an google voice action button next to `edittext`, so whenever the user wants to input something into edittext he just taps the button, speaks and gets into the `edittext`.
Can we do something like that, rather that the user has to tap on the `edittext` to open up soft keyboard choose voice action button and then speak which gets printed on to `edittext`.

Looking forward to your reply.

thanks.

Comment: You can launch speech recognition `Intent` anyway you like, including some button you placed next to that `EditText`. And of course you can than put the results anywhere you like, including the neighboring `EditText`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

into your onClick() and let onActivityResult() fill in the result.

Comment: thanks it works but `onActivityResult` I am getting  request code as `1` resultcode as `-1` and data null. what could be the mistake I might be doing for not getting the data.